# change siteid in ebay API call

Tags: php, curl, opencart

I need to connect with the eBay motors site using a function in openbay which is an opencart extension. The site id for eBay motors is 100, but for the life of me I cannot get it to change with the way this function is written, am I missing something here???

`API function call`

```
public function openbay_call($call, array $post = NULL, array $options = array(), $content_type = 'json', $statusOverride = false){

        if(defined("HTTPS_CATALOG")){
            $domain = HTTPS_CATALOG;
        }else{
            $domain = HTTPS_SERVER;
        }

        $data = array(
            'token'             => $this->token, 
            'language'          => $this->config->get('openbay_language'), 
            'secret'            => $this->secret, 
            'server'            => $this->server, 
            'domain'            => $domain, 
            'openbay_version'   => (int)$this->config->get('openbay_version'),
            'data'              => $post, 
            'content_type'      => $content_type
        );

       $defaults = array(
            CURLOPT_POST            => 1,
            CURLOPT_HEADER          => 0,
            CURLOPT_URL             => $this->url.$call,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1",
            CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT   => 1,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
            CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE    => 1,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 0,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => http_build_query($data, '', "&")       
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, ($options + $defaults));
        if( ! $result = curl_exec($ch)){
            $this->log('openbay_call() - Curl Failed '.curl_error($ch).' '.curl_errno($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);

        /* There may be some calls we just dont want to log */
        if(!in_array($call, $this->noLog)){
            $this->log('openbay_call() - Result of : "'.$result.'"');
        }
        /* JSON RESPONSE */
        if($content_type == 'json'){
            $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($result);

            /* some json data may have BOM due to php not handling types correctly */
            if($encoding == 'UTF-8') {
              $result = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $result);    
            } 

            $result             = json_decode($result, 1);
            $this->lasterror    = $result['error'];
            $this->lastmsg      = $result['msg'];

            if(!empty($result['data'])){
                return $result['data'];
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        /* XML RESPONSE */
        }elseif($content_type == 'xml'){
            $result             = simplexml_load_string($result);
            $this->lasterror    = $result->error;
            $this->lastmsg      = $result->msg;

            if(!empty($result->data)){
                return $result->data;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }else{
        $this->log('openbay_call() - OpenBay not active');
        $this->log('openbay_call() - Data: '.serialize($post));
    }
}
```

`predefined parameters within the class` - probably don't help but included anyways.

```
public function __construct($registry) {
    $this->registry     = $registry;
    $this->token        = $this->config->get('openbaypro_token');
    $this->secret       = $this->config->get('openbaypro_secret');
    $this->logging      = $this->config->get('openbaypro_logging');
    $this->tax      = $this->config->get('tax');
    $this->server       = 1;
    $this->lasterror    = '';
    $this->lastmsg      = '';
}
```

`the function call`

```
$this->data['test_category_features'] = $this->ebay->openbay_call('listing/getCategoryFeatures/', array('id' => 35618));
```

Everything works but how would i get this to change siteid to 100, the only way I can figure it out is to re-write my own API call class, but the client is paying for the subscription to openbay and wants to use the API calls through them, so I have to use there function. Im trying to return eBay motors category features so he can list them the same way he has been for years "used parts". If you don't switch to the eBay motors site id "100" then it will not return the category variations needed or more less accept the categories when trying to add products to eBay through the opencart extension.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated, really stuck here!!! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this page: http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/merchandising/docs/Concepts/SiteIDToGlobalID.html you need to add "... X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID HTTP header for each API call" so add that to the curl options.

Comment: I have to write my own API call apparently they filter the calls through there site. Thankyou